# Is there a way to set your default region in Dynamo DB Console? Mine always opens in the wrong region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When I open AWS to go to DynamoDB, it sets my region to n California. Our db  is actually on Oregon.

How do I solve this? I have scoured the internet and not found a solution

To Clarify: Whenever I log back in, it defaults to N California. I need it to default to Oregon.

Comment: When you say database do you mean table? Also when you look at the 'overview tab' for the table what region is it in?

Comment: No I don't mean table. It say Oregon, like I stated. And yes I'm speaking of the aws management console. Whenever I log back in, it defaults to N California. I need it to default to Oregon.

Answer (score 0):

Bookmark the URL of the DynamoDB console when you are in the Oregon region and for next time, use the bookmarked URL to open DynamoDB.